# How to compare two variables using if-statements?

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I want to compare the two values stored in `e1_var` and `e2_var`. If they are the same, I want to show a button on the master window; if they don't match, I want to show another button. What I have tried so far doesn't work. Can somebody show me how to do this?

```
def lockscreen():
    locks = Toplevel(width=500,height=500)
    locks.title('Lock Screen')
    l1 = Label(locks,text="Enter 4 Digit Lock Code")
    l1.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=3)
    e1=Entry(locks, bd=5)
    e1.grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=3)
    e1_var=StringVar()
    e1["textvariable"]=e1_var

    def insert_1():
        e1.insert(INSERT,1)
    def insert_2():
        e1.insert(INSERT,2)
    def insert_3():
        e1.insert(INSERT,3)
    def insert_4():
        e1.insert(INSERT,4)
    def insert_5():
        e1.insert(INSERT,5)
    def insert_6():
        e1.insert(INSERT,6)
    def insert_7():
        e1.insert(INSERT,7)
    def insert_8():
        e1.insert(INSERT,8)
    def insert_9():
        e1.insert(INSERT,9)
    def insert_0():
        e1.insert(INSERT,0)       
    def lock_action():
        lock_code=e1_var.get()
        print (lock_code)
        Button(master,width=50,height=50, text='Unlock', command=unlock).place(x=0,y=0)


    Button(locks, width=3, height=3, text='1', command =insert_1).grid(row=3,column=1)          
    Button(locks, width=3, height=3, text='2', command =insert_2).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Button(locks, width=3, height=3, text='3', command =insert_3).grid(row=3,column=3)
    Button(locks, width=3, height=3, text='4', command =insert_4).grid(row=4,column=1)
    Button(locks, width=3, height=3, text='5', command =insert_5).grid(row=4,column=2)
    Button(locks, width=3, height=3, text='6', command =insert_6).grid(row=4,column=3)
    Button(locks, width=3, height=3, text='7', command =insert_7).grid(row=5,column=1)
    Button(locks, width=3, height=3, text='8', command =insert_8).grid(row=5,column=2)
    Button(locks, width=3, height=3, text='9', command =insert_9).grid(row=5,column=3)
    Button(locks, width=3, height=3, text='Close').grid(row=6,column=1)
    Button(locks, width=3, height=3, text='0', command =insert_0).grid(row=6,column=2)
    block=Button(locks, width=3, height=3, text='Lock',command=lock_action)
    block.grid(row=6,column=3)

    def unlock():
        ulocks = Toplevel(width=500,height=500)
        ulocks.title('Unlock Screen')
        l2 = Label(ulocks,text="Enter 4 Digit Unlock Code")
        l2.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=3)
        e2=Entry(ulocks, bd=5)
        e2.grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=3)
        e2_var=StringVar()
        e2["textvariable"]=e2_var


        def insert_u1():
            e2.insert(INSERT,1)
        def insert_u2():
            e2.insert(INSERT,2)
        def insert_u3():
            e2.insert(INSERT,3)
        def insert_u4():
            e2.insert(INSERT,4)
        def insert_u5():
            e2.insert(INSERT,5)
        def insert_u6():
            e2.insert(INSERT,6)
        def insert_u7():
            e2.insert(INSERT,7)
        def insert_u8():
            e2.insert(INSERT,8)
        def insert_u9():
            e2.insert(INSERT,9)
        def insert_u0():
            e2.insert(INSERT,0)       
        def unlock_action():
            unlock_code=e2_var.get()
            if lock_code==unlock_code
                Button(master,width=800, height=800, text='IT WORKS!!!!!!!').place(x=400,y=0)
                else if
                Button(master,width=800,height=800, text='It doesnt work :-(').place(x=20,y=0)

        Button(ulocks, width=3, height=3, text='1', command =insert_u1).grid(row=3,column=1)          
        Button(ulocks, width=3, height=3, text='2', command =insert_u2).grid(row=3,column=2)
        Button(ulocks, width=3, height=3, text='3', command =insert_u3).grid(row=3,column=3)
        Button(ulocks, width=3, height=3, text='4', command =insert_u4).grid(row=4,column=1)
        Button(ulocks, width=3, height=3, text='5', command =insert_u5).grid(row=4,column=2)
        Button(ulocks, width=3, height=3, text='6', command =insert_u6).grid(row=4,column=3)
        Button(ulocks, width=3, height=3, text='7', command =insert_u7).grid(row=5,column=1)
        Button(ulocks, width=3, height=3, text='8', command =insert_u8).grid(row=5,column=2)
        Button(ulocks, width=3, height=3, text='9', command =insert_u9).grid(row=5,column=3)
        Button(ulocks, width=3, height=3, text='Close').grid(row=6,column=1)
        Button(ulocks, width=3, height=3, text='0', command =insert_u0).grid(row=6,column=2)
        Button(ulocks, width=3, height=3, text='Unlock',command=unlock_action).grid(row=6,column=3)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have fundamental syntax problems with your `if` statement. See this: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Side hint: any time you keep repeating the same line(s) of code with `insert_1`, `insert_2`, `insert3`... it means you're doing something wrong. We invented computer programming so that we wouldn't have to do repetitive tasks like that

Comment: thanks i will look at that link and how would you shrink the insert part?

Comment: @user2996828: For loop and a lambda expression. Something like `for i in range(10): Button(... text=str(i), command =lambda: e1.insert(INSERT, i)...`.

Answer (score 0):

[**The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar):**](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

> The ***get*** method returns the current value of the variable, as a Python ***object***. For BooleanVar variables, the returned value is 0 for false, and 1 for true. For DoubleVar variables, the returned value is a Python float. For IntVar, it’s an integer. **For *StringVar*, it’s either an ASCII string or a Unicode string, depending on the contents**.

The first test compares two `StringVar` objects. Since each is its own instance, they are unique. You would have to do a deep-compare to determine equality.

The second is just a String compare.

```
from Tkinter import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Tk()

    e1_var = StringVar()
    e2_var = StringVar()

    print 'Test 1 [Object compare]: {}'\
        .format('same' if e1_var == e2_var else 'different')
    print 'Test 2 [String compare]: {}'\
        .format('same' if e1_var.get() == e2_var.get() else 'different')
```

**Output:**

```
Test 1 [Object compare]: different
Test 2 [String compare]: same
```